# Every selected mesh is always outlined orange

Tags: interface, selection-tools

Every selected mesh (cube, sphere etc.) is **always outlined orange**. The problem seems to concern `mesh` objects only. since lights, cameras aren't impacted.

Thus I can't distinguish the last selected object anymore which usually is outlined yellow.

Tried default settings in blender 2.93 & 3.2 to no avail.

[image]

Comment: This is strange - Unfortunately I cannot re-create this problem, no matter what I try.

Answer (score 0):

I can see that the last selected object is visible in the Outliner, so check *Edit > Preferences*

[image]

This defines the color of the *Active Object*

Comment: Thanks, apparently this only changes the bounding box center dot of the selection. At least in my case.